# Extend OOP validation function to support arrays

Tags: php, arrays, validation, oop

I'm using the following validation function to validate forms on my site.  I would like to extend it so that it supports arrays.

For example at the moment I might use it on the following form:

```
<input type="text" name="agency_name">
```

But I would like to adapt it so that it can validate fields in the following format (posted arrays):

```
<input type="text" name="agency_name[]">
<input type="text" name="agency_name[]">
```

The function I am using is:

```
public function check($source, $items = array()) {
foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
    foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {
        $value = $source[$item];
        $item = escape($item);

        if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
            $this->addError("{$item} is required");
        } 
        else if (!empty($value)) {
            switch($rule) {
                case 'min':
                    if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                        $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                    }
                break;
                case 'max':
                    if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
                        $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                    }
                break;
                case 'matches':
                    if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                        $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}.");
                    }
                break;
                case 'unique':
                    $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));

                    if($check->count()) {
                        $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
if(empty($this->_errors)) {
    $this->_passed = true;
}
}
```

Does anyone know how to modify it easily to support validation of array fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: switch/case !== oop. Refactor conditional with polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Before your validation function and after the document has loaded

```
$("#NameOfTrigger").click(function() {
    var items = [];
    $("#NameOfFormOtParentContainer input[type=text]").each(function() {        
        items.add($(this).val);
    });        
});
```

//then pass the items array to your validation function